# OutputDebugString() not showing message in DebugView, Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windbg, debugview

I know there're guides on the Internet, and here is what I've done so far.

- Run DebugView as Administrator. In DebugView, I have checked "Capture Win32"
- I have set the following filter keys & restart the computer:
  `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter" /V DEFAULT /t REG_DWORD /d 0xf`
  `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter" /v DEFAULT /t REG_DWORD /d 0xFFFFFFFF`
- I have debugged my app to make sure the OutputDebugString() is indeed executed.

But, the message from OutputDebugString() is still not showed in DebugView (if not debugged with Windbg) and Windbg (if debugged).

Comment: 'Debug Print Filter' controls kernel-mode debug output, while 'OutputDebugString' is a user-mode API. What type of process are you calling OutputDebugString from, and does it make a difference if you also enable 'Capture Global Win32' in DbgView.

Comment: With DebugView++, I could see the message.

Comment: DebugView++ is better anyway, especially Performance.